# way to delete Route/Scene from stack?

Tags: react-native, react-router, navigator

Is there a correct way to delete one route/scene from the stack (history)? I can see the stack in Actions.currentRouter, and I thought it would be as easy as deleting an element from an array, but this does not have the desired behavior.

I basically need this, for example, if a user fills a form and submits, then gets to a new scene, and if the user hits back, skip the form scene, and take him to the second to last scene where he was, I don't want to reset the stack btw.

Thanks

Comment: Which navigation component are you using? Navigator, NavigatorIOS or NavigationExperimental? I too would have assumed that deleting the element from the stack array would have done the trick...

Comment: I'm using react-native-router-flux, which I think uses Navigator

Comment: Actually it uses a separated fork of ExperimentalNavigation since v3.0.9: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#supported-configurations

Comment: I haven't migrated to v3, so I think the older versions do use Navigator

Answer (score 3):

I am also using **react-native-router-flux** and faced same problem. I solved this problem by using **Actions.replace('Scene-Key')** offered by **react-native-router-flux**.

So you can try :

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

.

.

.

Actions.replace('Scene-Key')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, I edited my answer, kindly informed me, if any thing I missed in formatting, as I am new on **StackOverflow**